# Bottom border in actionbar only appear in tab

Tags: android-actionbar

In my app I have an action bar . The problem is when I test my app in tab , there is a border under the action bar . (Screenshot attached below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKNRF.jpg

But in any other phone there is no border (Screen shot attached below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzTeO.jpg

Here is the code for my actionbar

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/Navbar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

What is the reason of showing that border only in tab ? How can I remove it ?
Note: The OS of that tab is Android 4.4.2 KitKat

Answer (score 0):

can you give a try with null and not white color.

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```